# How do I get the url slug inside the dashboard for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-field, permalinks, dashboard

I have added some custom fields inside my blog posts, I need to insert in one of them my permalink from dashboard, how do I do it? How do I get this permalink inside the dashboard?

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `get_permalink()`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: @jaswrks won't it take the permalink of the edit page? like website.com/post.php?post=46976&action=edit  rather than website.com/post_name

Comment: No, the permalink is the user-facing URL. You're thinking of https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/

Comment: oh yes, you are right, you can post an answer so I accept your answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the permalink using [`get_permalink()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink)

To retrieve the edit link for a post, use: [`get_edit_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/)